# Blazor Wasm setting end user defined startpage

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly

In my application I have many areas for different kinds of users. Controlled by roles.
So I would like to give the user an option to set a preferred startpage.

Deep Linking works, so no problems there.

My first attempt was this

```
@code{
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }
    [Inject] private NavigationManager  Navigation { get; set; }

    private void LoginSucceeded(RemoteAuthenticationState state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("navigate to DepartmentAccess");
        // This works with on extra login
        Navigation.NavigateTo("/DepartmentAccess", true);
        // This loads 3 or more times
        // state.ReturnUrl = "/DepartmentAccess";
    }
```

}

Then I tried altering the return url in RedirectToLogin.razor. Here I added “MyStartPage”

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using Zeus.Client.PortfolioRights

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(Navigation.Uri)/MyStartPage}");
    }
}
```

This has absolutely no effekt!

Okay time to dig a little deeper

It’s the RemoteAuthenticatorViewCore that holds all the code related to the login process.
This function handles the Login state. It’s called after the redirect from Azure AD

```
  private async Task ProcessLogIn(string returnUrl)
        {
            AuthenticationState.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            var result = await AuthenticationService.SignInAsync(new RemoteAuthenticationContext<TAuthenticationState>
            {
                State = AuthenticationState
            });

            switch (result.Status)
            {
                case RemoteAuthenticationStatus.Redirect:
                    break;
                case RemoteAuthenticationStatus.Success:
                    await OnLogInSucceeded.InvokeAsync(result.State);
                    await NavigateToReturnUrl(GetReturnUrl(result.State, returnUrl));
                    break;
                case RemoteAuthenticationStatus.Failure:
                    _message = result.ErrorMessage;
                    Navigation.NavigateTo(ApplicationPaths.LogInFailedPath);
                    break;
                case RemoteAuthenticationStatus.OperationCompleted:
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid authentication result status '{result.Status}'.");
            }
        }
```

The input parameter “returnUri” are set from this function

```
private string GetReturnUrl(TAuthenticationState state, string defaultReturnUrl = null)
        {
            if (state?.ReturnUrl != null)
            {
                return state.ReturnUrl;
            }

            var fromQuery = QueryStringHelper.GetParameter(new Uri(Navigation.Uri).Query, "returnUrl");
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fromQuery) && !fromQuery.StartsWith(Navigation.BaseUri))
            {
                // This is an extra check to prevent open redirects.
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid return url. The return url needs to have the same origin as the current page.");
            }

            return fromQuery ?? defaultReturnUrl ?? Navigation.BaseUri;
        }
```

So I wonder. Why is the “defaultReturnUrl” not set when I alter the return uri?

```
Navigation.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(Navigation.Uri)/MyStartPage}
```

I guess that I don't understand the login flow. But got a feeling that I am close.
Just need to find a way to set the defaultReturnUrl

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below points can be worked around.

1. The first step in getting a page (component) ready to participate in routing is to assign the component a route. You do that in the cshmtl file, using the page directive.
   `@page` "/redirectpage"      above @inject NavigationManager NavManager
2. Make sure to Add CascadingAuthenticationState and  `<AuthorizeView>`  in apps.razor and LoginDisplay component.It is responsible to display pages that the user is authorised to see.
   (or)
3. If the page component for the route contains an authorize attribute (`@attribute [Authorize]`) then the user must be logged in, otherwise they will be redirected to the login page.

Example: if you wanted to secure the Counter.razor page just add an Authorize attribute to the top:

```html
   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
      @attribute [Authorize]
```

Or

@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "finance")]

Add this to the pages that require authentication.

**References:**

1. [Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app with the
   Authentication library | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#redirecttologin-component)
2. [Using Azure Active Directory to Secure Blazor WebAssembly Hosted
   Apps (code-maze.com)](https://code-maze.com/using-azure-active-directory-to-secure-blazor-webassembly-hosted-apps/)
3. [Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app with Azure
   Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thanks I got this. And it's already implemented